# Multiple File Upload Tool

Tags: file-upload

I'm looking for a web based multiple file upload tool, preferably free, or an easy way/ideas to make such a tool.

Scenario:

- Have team members upload multiple pictures/videos/files to a folder on the website.

Criteria:

- **Has to be web based** - users should be able to use it from a page in the website.
- Language: PHP/Flash Combination is preferred, but anything goes - the website is hosted on linux shared hosting.

Comment: Which language? For what? U want a file upload control for your website?

Comment: Do you want a multiple file upload tool?

Comment: Not a good question.  You didn't mention operating systems for the clients or your requirements, file types / sizes, etc.

There are about a million solutions.  There's all sorts of FTP clients, SFTP, etc, which often support mirrored folders or entire web sites.

Additionally, there's solutions like WebDAV and a whole host of file sharing services.

In short, a lot more information is needed for anyone to be able to offer any meaningful advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another good uploader is uploadify.  It is a jquery uploader.  I use it for my site and it has been very helpful an easy to use.  You can find it here http://www.uploadify.com/

Answer (score 2):

[SWF Upload](http://swfupload.org/) is great and free.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very vague and broad. you will need to narrow it down and tell us where exactly you're having problems with. Is it a script or suggestion for a framework you want?

What does multiple mean...? please describe properly what you want.

Comment: I meant multiple files in the sense that users should be able to upload more than one file at once, similar to a ftp client, but online through a web page.